# Thunderbird on MacOS, quickfilter is not working?

Tags: macos, email, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

Thunderbird quickfilter has stopped working since a while ago.

I found a link that says it could be due to large amount of emails. I have a bunch of accounts setup so that could be it, but still annoying that there is this limitation.

I was initially able to get around it as one thread online mentioned to open an "inbox" in a new window, but that seem to now also have stopped working.

I've tried to repair the tunderbird index as well a couple of times.

Note, the global search seems to work fine, but not the quick filter.

Is there a way to fix quickfilter?

Could be related:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS this can be resolved with:

sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Thunderbird/Profiles/abcdefg.default/session.json